# how to say this field has email annotation from outside

Tags: spring-boot, junit

```
@NotNull(message = "emailAddress is mandatory")
@NotEmpty(message = "emailAddress cannot be empty")
@Email(message = "Invalid Email")
private String emailAddress;
```

I just want to know from outside , emailAdress has Email annotation.
Is there any way that we can say it is an email annotaion?

Comment: Why? What is it you want to achieve? If you want to express explicitly that this is an emailaddress, than create a value object `EmailAddress` to make those things explicit. Don't rely on annotations for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection for this. The following test passes:

```
 public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws NoSuchFieldException {
        HasEmailAddressValidator hasEmailAddressValidator = new HasEmailAddressValidator();
        boolean result = hasEmailAddressValidator.hasEmailAddress(MyClass.class);

        assertTrue(result);
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    static
    class HasEmailAddressValidator {
        public boolean hasEmailAddress(Class<?> clazz) throws NoSuchFieldException {
            return clazz.getDeclaredField("email").isAnnotationPresent(Email.class);
        }
    }

    @Data
    static
    class MyClass {
        @Email(message = "this is an email address")
        private String email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I understand what you meant and it worked. One more question. What if I want to get size annotation from password field. I also want what size needs to be handled for password?

Answer (score 0):

Create your custome Annotation.

```
`import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target({ TYPE, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmailValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidEmail {

    String message() default "Invalid Email";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

// Email Validator

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidEmail, String> {
    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String username, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return (validateEmail(username));
    }

    private boolean validateEmail(final String email) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

// Now in your DTO and Model

```
    @ValidEmail
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, message = "Invalid Email")
    private String email;
```

Comment: Question was "How to determine if field has `@Email` annotation", not "How to validate email"